# What type of sentence is it?

Tags: sentence-structure

> The government cap on payments for medical services is thought to have encouraged doctors to perform off-the-books, and potentially far more lucrative, services like illegal abortions.

Is it a simple sentence, compound sentence or a complex sentence?

Comment: It's a complex sentence consisting of one main clause (the whole sentence) and several subordinate clauses. But, it's not important to talk of simple, compound and complex sentences. Identifying the main clause and subordinate clause is what's important.

Comment: [The government cap on payments for medical services is [thought [to have [encouraged doctors [to perform off-the-books, and potentially far more lucrative, services like illegal abortions]]]]].

Answer (score 1):

> The government cap on payments for medical services is thought to have encouraged doctors to perform off-the-books, and potentially far more lucrative, services like illegal abortions.

Q. Is it a simple sentence, compound sentence or a complex sentence?

### Please noted I have not answered the additional question after the edit

A. The quoted example is not a good one. However I would suggest it is none of what you have referenced above.

"The government cap on payments for medical services is thought to have encouraged doctors to perform off-the-books (services),

and

potentially far more lucrative services

like

illegal abortions".

> The **Four Types of Sentence Structure**

> A Complex Sentence. A complex sentence has an independent clause and at least one dependent clause. For example:
> Diplomacy is the art of saying "nice doggie" until you can find a rock. (Will Rogers, 1879-1935)

> A Compound Sentence. A compound sentence has at least two independent clauses. For example:
> Some men are born mediocre, some men achieve mediocrity, and some men have mediocrity thrust upon them. (Joseph Heller, 1923-1999) (Jane Wagner)
> (This example has three independent clauses.)

> A Simple Sentence. A simple sentence has just one independent clause. For example:
> A country can be judged by the quality of its proverbs. (German Proverb)

> **A Compound-Complex Sentence**. A compound-complex sentence has at least two independent clauses and at least one dependent clause. For example:
> I stopped believing in Santa Claus when he asked for my autograph in a department store, but I still want to believe in him.

Ref[grammar-monster](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/compound_sentence.htm)

Comment: If it's none of them....then what to call these types of sentences....and I have edited the question box for adding another sentence in which I have confusion... it's related to the same topic.

Comment: @RADS Just read the four types of Sentence Structure. Then you may deduce why I highlighted the last one which was not on your list. Please post the new question as exactly that, to avoid us having to make grossly confusing answers because you have to many questions together. (which unfortunately happens all too often, on this site).

Comment: So.....we have only to ask one question at one time?

Comment: @RADS https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask If you ask multiple questions we have to give multiple answers, which becomes confusing, especially when they are on a similar subject.

Comment: The analysis is: [The government cap on payments for medical services is [thought [to have [encouraged doctors [to perform off-the-books, and potentially far more lucrative, services like illegal abortions]]]]].